# Hive connector to HDP 2.6 not working

Tags: knime

I am using KNIME 3.4.1 and trying to connect it to HDP 2.6.1 using this [KNIME blog post](https://www.knime.com/blog/speaking-kerberos-with-knime-big-data-extensions).

The kerberos ticket is present

```
E:\Omkar\Development\Software\Analysis\KNIME>klist

Credentials cache: C:\Users\ojoqcu\krb5cc_ojoqcu

Default principal: ojoqcu@GLOBAL.SCD.COM, 1 entry found.

[1]  Service Principal:  krbtgt/GLOBAL.SCD.COM@GLOBAL.SCD.COM
     Valid starting:     Oct 06,  2017 10:49:39
     Expires:            Oct 06,  2017 20:49:39

E:\Omkar\Development\Software\Analysis\KNIME>knime.exe

E:\Omkar\Development\Software\Analysis\KNIME>
```

The krb5.conf file is present under KNIME jre

```
[libdefaults]
  renew_lifetime = 7d
  forwardable = true
  default_realm = GLOBAL.SCD.COM
  ticket_lifetime = 10h
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  dns_lookup_kdc = true
  default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
  allow_weak_crypto = yes

[logging]
  default = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
  admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
  kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log

[realms]
  GLOBAL.SCD.COM = {
    default_domain = sss.se.com
  }

  SE = {
    default_domain = sss.se.com
  }
```

I have added the Hortonworks Hive JDBC jar, yet, the driver doesn't show up in the config.
[image: jdbc_jar_path]

[image: hive-connector_config]

The attached screenshot shows the config. of the Hive connector, upon execution, I get the following error :

```
ERROR Hive Connector       0:1        Exception creating Kerberos based jdbc connection. Error: null
ERROR Hive Connector       0:1        Execute failed: Could not create connection to database: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://www.knime.com/forum/knime-general/hive-through-jdbc) on the KNIME forum might help - in short, it looks like you need to use 'add directory' rather than just adding the driver jar file to add both the driver and companion libraries.  That is also supported by this paragraph from the blog post you mention:

> For Hive this will give you a file called hive_jdbc_zip. Inside this ZIP file is another ZIP file: Cloudera_HiveJDBC41_.zip. It contains a folder with the driver files. **Add this folder** in KNIME under File > Preferences > KNIME > Databases (**via Directory**). After this, you need to restart KNIME Analytics Platform.

Comment: I have tried both directory and jar file, the result is the same

Comment: Did you try the enhanced logging option described at the end of the post?  Did it reveal anything?  It might be worth also posting on the KNIME forum - there is a post with a currently broken link [here](https://www.knime.com/forum/knime-general/hive-through-jdbc) which looks like it describes a similar issue